# Interface gráfica dinâmica após requisição MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Gente é o seguinte,  estou querendo carregar todos esses dados na minha interface gráfica, a ideia é que o usuário digite o cpf(primary key) dele e depois disso seja carregado todos esses dados para ele atualizar, quero saber como faço para que esse cpf após o usuário,  digitar carregue os dados, tentei fazer ae mais nao está dando certo.

```
DadosFuncionario funcionario = new DadosFuncionario();

try{
    Conexao.Conectar();

    String  sql = "select * from funcionario";

    PreparedStatement query;

    query = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    query.setString(1, campoDigCpf.getText());
    // query.executeQuery();
    ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery(sql);

    //tapete.setNome(rs.getString("nome"); 
    while (rs.next()) {
        String cargoOcupado = rs.getString("cargoOcupado");
        String nome = rs.getString("nome");
        String cpf = rs.getString("cpf");
        int rg = rs.getInt("rg");
        String orgaoExped = rs.getString("orgaoExped");
        Date dataExped = rs.getDate("dataExped");
        Date dataDeNascimento = rs.getDate("dataDeNascimento");
        String email = rs.getString("email");
        String estadoCivil = rs.getString("estadoCivil");
        String sexo = rs.getString("sexo");
        int cnh = rs.getInt("cnh");
        int titulo = rs.getInt("titulo");
        int zona = rs.getInt("zona");
        int secao = rs.getInt("secao");
        int carteiraTrabalho = rs.getInt("carteiraTrabalho");
        int serieCtrabalho = rs.getInt("serieCtrabalho");
        int cartResevista = rs.getInt("cartResevista");
        int serieResevista = rs.getInt("serieResevista");
        String racaCor = rs.getString("racaCor");
        int pis = rs.getInt("pis");
    }    
    query.close();


    String sql2 = "select * from endereco";
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql2);

    while (rs1.next()) {
        int numero = rs1.getInt("numero");
        int numeroEmpresa = rs1.getInt("numeroEmpresa");
        String rua = rs1.getString("rua");
        String ruaEmpresa = rs1.getString("ruaEmpresa");
        String bairro = rs1.getString("bairro");
        String bairroEmpresa = rs1.getString("bairroEmpresa");
        String cidade = rs1.getString("cidade");
        String cidadeEmpresa = rs1.getString("cidadeEmpresa");
        int cep = rs1.getInt("cep");
        int cepEmpresa = rs1.getInt("cepEmpresa");
        String ufFuncionario = rs1.getString("ufFuncionario");
        String ufEmpresa = rs1.getString("ufEmpresa");
    }    
    stmt.close();


    String sql3 = "select * from dadosprofissionais";
    PreparedStatement stmt1;
    stmt1 = con.prepareStatement(sql3);
    ResultSet rs2 = stmt1.executeQuery(sql3);

    while (rs2.next()) { 
        String diretoria = rs2.getString("diretoria");
        String departamento = rs2.getString("departamento");
        String divisao = rs2.getString("divisao");
        int matricula = rs2.getInt("matricula");
        String inss = rs2.getString("inss");
        int contaCorrente = rs2.getInt("contaCorrente");
        int agenciaBanco = rs2.getInt("agenciaBanco");
        int numeroBanco = rs2.getInt("numeroBanco");
        String nivelEscolar = rs2.getString("nivelEscolar");
        String periodo = rs2.getString("periodo");
        Date dataAdmissao = rs2.getDate("dataAdmissao");
        String conselho = rs2.getString("conselho");
    }    
    stmt1.close();


    String sql4 = "select * from informacoesgerais";
    PreparedStatement stmt2;
    stmt2 = con.prepareStatement(sql4);
    ResultSet rs3 = stmt2.executeQuery(sql4);

    while (rs3.next()) { 
        String concordo = rs3.getString("concordo");
        String observacoes = rs3.getString("observacoes");
        Date dataFormulario = rs3.getDate("dataFormulario");
    }    
    stmt2.close();


    String sql5 = "select * from telefone";
    PreparedStatement stmt3;
    stmt3 = con.prepareStatement(sql5);
    ResultSet rs4 = stmt3.executeQuery(sql5);

    while (rs4.next()) {  
        int foneFuncionario = rs4.getInt("foneFuncionario");
        int celFuncionario = rs4.getInt("celFuncionario");
        int ramal = rs4.getInt("ramal");
        int foneEmpresa = rs4.getInt("foneEmpresa");
    }    
    stmt3.close();


    String sql6 = "select * from dependentes";
    PreparedStatement stmt4;
    stmt4 = con.prepareStatement(sql6);
    ResultSet rs5 = stmt4.executeQuery(sql6);

    while (rs5.next()) {   
        String conjugue = rs5.getString("conjugue");
        String pai = rs5.getString("pai");
        String mae = rs5.getString("mae");
        int qtdDeFilhos = rs5.getInt("qtdDeFilhos");
        int totalDependentes = rs5.getInt("totalDependentes");
        String profissaoConjugue = rs5.getString("profissaoConjugue");
        String profissaoPai = rs5.getString("profissaoPai");
        String profissaoMae = rs5.getString("profissaoMae");
        String parenteEmpresa = rs5.getString("parenteEmpresa");
        String nomeParenEmpresa = rs5.getString("nomeParenEmpresa");
        String grauParentesco = rs5.getString("grauParentesco");
    }   
    stmt4.close();
    Conexao.con.close();

} catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu no erro sql...  " + e.getMessage());

}    

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados carregados com sucesso");
```

Comment: Digitar onde? Ta usando swing? A edição tinha deixado a pergunta mais clara, edite-a novamente, têm trechos confusos por causa da pontuação.

Comment: Estou usando swing,os select estão certos a unica coisa que falta e a parte que o usuário digita o cpf(que um id(primary key)), eu uso um botão que da um select que carrega todos esses dados,que e justamente todo esse código.

Comment: Voce está usando prepareStatement mas suas querys não tem argumentos e nem filtros. Revise suas querys, os argumentos do prepareStatement de nada servem se não forem informados na query onde eles devem ser substituídos.

Comment: Existe relação entre as tabelas(há campos de chave estrangeira entre eles)? Acho que da pra otimizar esse tanto de consulta, mas você precisa mostrar como está as tabelas e a relação entre elas.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está bem desorganizado, recomendo colocar cada consulta relacionada a Funcionários em métodos. Aqui tem um exemplo simples de como passar o cpf como parâmetro em uma consulta, tente adaptar conforme sua necessidade.

```
public  Funcionario buscar(String cpf) throws Exception {
        /* Define a SQL */
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("SELECT cargoOcupado, nome, cpf, rg, orgaoExped ");
        sql.append("FROM funcionario ");
        //Passa cpf como parametro pra consulta
        sql.append("WHERE cpf = '"+cpf+"' ");
        sql.append("ORDER BY nome ");

        /* Abre a conexão */
        Connection conn = Conexao.abrir();

        /* Mapeamento objeto relacional */
        PreparedStatement comando = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

        /* Executa a SQL e captura o resultado da consulta */
        ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();

        /* Cria um objeto para armazenar o resultado da consulta */
        Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();

        /* Percorre o resultado armazenando os valores em um objeto*/
        if (resultado.next()) {
            /* Cria um objeto para armazenar uma linha da consulta */
            funcionario.setCargo(resultado.getString("cargoOcupado"));
            funcionario.setNome(resultado.getString("nome"));
            funcionario.setCpf(resultado.getString("cpf"));
            funcionario.setRg(resultado.getString("rg"));
            funcionario.setOrgaoExpeditor(resultado.getString(" orgaoExped"));

        }

        /* Fecha a conexão */
        resultado.close();
        comando.close();
        conn.close();
        /* Retornao objeto contendo o resultado da consulta */
        return funcionario;
    }
```

Exemplo da chamada do método:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Teste t = new Teste();
    Funcionario f = new Funcionario();
    f = t.buscar("123-232-312-32");
}
```